# Can you retrieve the Omega breakpoint settings?

Tags: 7, theming

As the title suggests, is it possible to retrieve the Omega breakpoints you set in the settings for your subtheme via any kind of function or call? Like the ones from the picture.

[image: Omega breakpoints]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the answer to this, it's retrievable but if you want to use it for adding your own stylesheets in at the same breakpoints (like I did) you have to do it in the template.php file

This is what I did

```
$theme = alpha_get_theme();
$layouts = $theme->grids['alpha_default']['layouts'];
$keys = array_keys($layouts);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    return $layouts[$keys[$i]]['media'];
}
```

This will return (or print, whatever you want it to do) the media-queries/breakpoints to use for your own sake.